# How to unhide folders without knowing their names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have already asked a similar question to this but couldn't tweak it so that it would work. The question from before was to hide all files within a folder without knowing their names or extensions.

Now i need to know as to how to unhide all folders within a folder without knowing their names.

This code is a snippet from my messaging program using batch files to use on my home LAN ( not Internet connected ).

```
Cd c:/users/Admin/desktop/messenger/users

For /d D%% in (*) do (

Attrib -h -s *

)

Tree
Pause
```

My problem is that the for command seems to execute but when tree is run it still shows that no subfolders exist

Comment: What problem are you having with the batch code you've posted? You need to be specific here, and explain the problem you're having along with the code you've tried. "I have this code" with no other information makes it difficult to provide you with help.

Comment: I have edited it for easier understanding @Ken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` command excludes hidden files/folders by default.  You have to alter the command to include them.  From within a batch file:

```
cd /d c:/users/Admin/desktop/messenger/users
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /ad /ah /b') do attrib -h -s "%%d"
```

The `/f` option tells it to execute the `dir /ad /ah /b` command and hand each item it finds to the `%%d` variable to process in the `do` portion of the `for` statement.  If you just run the `dir` command at a DOS prompt, you will see that it returns a list of only the hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother for running commands in Windows Command Prompt.

Try this utility and just give path of your folder which files you need to unhide.

[www.vhghorecha.in/unhide-all-files-folders-virus/](http://www.vhghorecha.in/unhide-all-files-folders-virus/)

Happy Knowledge Sharing